# How can I import specific table from MySQL to PostgreSQL with pgloader?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration, pgloader

I have MySQL and PostgreSQL databases. And I want to migrate only **one** of 10 tables from MySQL to PostgreSQL with **pgloader**.

Whole Database migrates with no problem.

Comment: *"How can I import specific table from MySQL to PostgreSQL with pgloader?"* Pretty sure it's in the manual [Migrating a MySQL Database to PostgreSQL](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/mysql.html)   notice the `LOAD DATABASE
     FROM      mysql://root@localhost/sakila
     INTO postgresql://localhost:54393/sakila` part which is explained in the manual.-> `mysql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?option=value&...]`

Comment: @Medevin: regarding the above, note the (commented out) line ` -- INCLUDING ONLY TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~/film/, 'actor'`.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: That's worked for me.